# Is there a way to add one day in UTC formated excel "general" cell?

Tags: excel

I need to add 1 day in `2019-05-23T00:00:00Z`, then expand this to 3-months from the excel bottom-right corner of the cell.

The expected result is `2019-05-24T00:00:00Z`.

I already tried:
`=A8+TIME(24;0;0)` with no seccess.

I dont want to convert my time i only want to add 1 day.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `= A8 + 1`? Oh wait, are you storing the dates as text?

Comment: @GSerg thanks for your reply,i tried  ```= A8 + 1``` but also didnt work, yes the values are stored as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert to date then add then convert back:

```
=TEXT(REPLACE(REPLACE($A$1,20,1,""),11,1," ")+ROW(1:1),"yyyy-mm-dd\Thh:mm:ss\Z")
```

For your local settings it appears you need to replace the `,` delimiter to `;`

[image]